# Replace empty value in dictionary Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have this data:

```
let data = datatable(Timestamp:datetime, Name:string, Value:int)
            [
             datetime(2022-02-18 10:00:00 AM), "Floor 1", 100,
            ];
    let mydict = dynamic(
        {
             "Id":"1",
             "Product": ""
        }
    );
data
| extend messageMetaData = mydict
| project Timestamp, Name, Value, messageMetaData = replace_string(tostring(messageMetaData), "", "Wheat")
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to replace the empty value in messageMetaData by a string. When running this code it is giving me the exact same result/

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: Try avoiding adding unnecessary complexity to your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print mydict = dynamic({"Id":"1", "Product": ""})
| extend messageMetaData = replace_string(tostring(mydict), '""', '"Wheat"')
```

| mydict | messageMetaData |
| --- | --- |
| {"Id":"1","Product":""} | {"Id":"1","Product":"Wheat"} |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAy2MMQvCMBBGd8H/cHxLGujiWnBzcRDcHOXIHTVg0pJcwWL7363o8njLe2OJ2SjNEoPRkWTOnGJo3jgLOhzQEq5lkCkYOgJWv98tpC/TLJS0Vu71osYnNt7youOTg96rbdu%20seEvv79vyQHuy9tD2eD8B0K%20Gkd/AAAA)

Comment: David דודו Markovitz thank you so much :)